# Different behaviour between "int &&" and "auto &&"

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, if I try to do this:

```
int x = 5;

int && y = x;
```

It will fail to compile, with an error telling that an r-value reference cannot bind to an lvalue.

However if I do:

```
int x = 5;

auto && y = x;
```

It compiles with no errors. Why is it happening? I tried to get the type of `y` but `typeid()` takes away the reference attributes. Does `auto &&` automatically collapses to a `&` or `&&` depending on what is being assigned?

Comment: you mean `= x`, no? Don't forget you can always inspect the type with `typeid`

Comment: Recall that a forwarding (universal) reference is `<deduced type> &&`.

Comment: It is exactly as you say.

Comment: see [Universal References in C++11—Scott Meyers](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: Now the official name is [forwarding references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904462/whats-the-standard-official-name-for-universal-references/33904463#33904463)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case `int && y`, the variable `y` can bind to only *rvalue* which `x` is not.

In the second case `auto && y` however, the variable `y` can bind to anything, as the type of `y` would be deduced anyway — and reference-collapsing will be applied accordingly — which is why your code compiles:

```
auto && y = x;
```

Since `x` is an lvalue, `auto` is deduced to be `int&`, hence it becomes:

```
int& && y = x;
```

and after reference-collapsing, it becomes:

```
int & y = x;
```

which is fine.

---

To understand it in more detail, read about:

- Universal Reference (or *Forwarding* Reference, as it has been proposed to improve the terminology)
- Reference Collapsing

Hope that helps.

Comment: The draft working paper for the C++ standard defines the term _forwarding reference_ in 14.8.2.1 [temp.deduct.call] paragraph 3 (i.e., a corresponding proposal was accepted at some point).

Comment: @DietmarKühl, thanks!!! I have been fighting with improper 'universal reference' for some time.

Answer (score 2):

`int&&` is an r-value reference to `int`.
Whereas `auto&&` is a [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: I do not like the term universal reference. There is nothing universal about them.

Comment: @SergeyA The good thing about the term is that you immediately understood me without me having to wave my hands. I value that.

Comment: Max, see above - now we have a proper term.

Comment: @SergeyA I am going to tattoo "forwarding reference" on my chest tonight.

Comment: I'd certainly love to see the picture!

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, `auto` (in `auto&&`) would be anything which would make the code well-formed. In this case, `int& &&` is well-formed, since `int& &&` collapses to `int&` - thus all work well.