# const forwarding reference gives error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const std::string' to 'const std::string &&'

Tags: c++, c++17, forward-reference

The following gives a compiler error:

```
  #include <string>

  const std::string& get_name();

  int main(){
    auto&& name1 = get_name();//should bind to whatever
    const auto& name2 = get_name();//also ok
    const auto&& name3 = get_name();//<-not ok, why ?
    return 0;
  }
```

Link to godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/l6IQQ7

If I use `const auto&` it compiles - but that will not bind to value.
`auto&&` will be bind to anything so that naturally works as well.
However, what is the logic behind `const auto&&` not binding in this case ?
I know `auto&&` will preserve the constness - but is there a way to be `const` explicit and at the same time be *reference/value agnostic* ?

**Motivation:**

For 'normal programming work' inside functions etc. it would be great to be able to say something like: *"I do not care if it's a value or reference - but I do not change it for the rest of the function"*.

This should be possible given current language.

**Related question:** [Why adding `const` makes the universal reference as rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814939/why-adding-const-makes-the-universal-reference-as-rvalue)

Comment: A [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814939/why-adding-const-makes-the-universal-reference-as-rvalue)? This question asks about template type deduction, but as the rules are identical to `auto` in this case, I think we can close it?

Comment: @lubgr I did see that actually- It's not framed the same - also Im asking for a 'solution'

Comment: a 'solution' is to just use const auto&. it binds to everything. and you wont get any advantage if you somehow get a const rvalue ref

Comment: @phön ty, thats a bit surprising though, please write an answer with explaination.

Comment: @phön I mean, intuitively you would think a returned value into 'const reference' like that would be destructed after that statement.

Comment: @darune yes. but thats lifetime extention. you get it for rvalue refs and const lvalue refs. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For 'normal programming work' inside functions etc. it would be great
>   to be able to say something like: "I do not care if it's a value or
>   reference - but I do not change it for the rest of the function".

You already have the solution at hand for your motivation: use `const auto&`. `const auto&` will bind to:

- const lvalue refs
- lvalue refs
- const rvalue refs
- rvalue refs
- Additionally, it will extend the lifetime of returned values

So you got everything you need. Yes, it is different from a const rvalue ref, but that wont matter if you just use it, since you wont be able to move from it anyway, since it is const.

Last note: `auto&&` will always be a reference. its a forwarding reference with deduction, but your final variable will ALWAYS be a reference (rvalue ref or lvalue ref, but never a "value"). Maybe that was/is a misconception?