# Why does it not work when an lvalue-ref-arg and an rvalue-ref-arg are passed as the same forwarding-ref type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, forwarding-reference

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void f(T&& a, T&& b)
{}

int main()
{
    int n;
    f(n, std::move(n));
}
```

`T&&` is a forwarding reference type, so I think `decltype(a)` should be `int&` and `decltype(b)` should be `int&&`.

However, the code above generates the following error:

> main.cpp(13,2): error : no matching function for call to 'f'
>            f(n, std::move(n));
>
> main.cpp(7,6):  note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('int &' vs. 'int')
>
> void f(T&& a, T&& b)
>
> 1 error generated.

**Why does it not work when an lvalue-ref-arg and an rvalue-ref-arg are passed as the same forwarding-ref type?**

My compiler is clang 4.0.

Comment: T cannot be deduced in to two different types, that's how template argument deduction works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error is pretty straight forward, `T` cannot be deduced in `int&` and `int` at the same time. In order for this to work you would have to provide an additional template argument:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void f(T1&& a, T2&& b)
{}
```

### Reasoning

Template argument deduction follows special rules when dealing with [forwarding references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904462/whats-the-standard-official-name-for-universal-references) (a.k.a Universal references) which are based on [reference collapsing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2)

- U& & becomes U&
- U& && becomes U&
- U&& & becomes U&
- U&& && becomes U&&

for example if you have a function template:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&&) {}
```

1. If `foo` input is an lvalue of type `U`, `T` will be deducted to `U&`. Following the reference collapsing rules above the argument type will become `U&`.
2. If `foo` input is a rvalue of type `U`,  `T` will be deducted to `U` and consequently the argument type will be `U&&`.

Now following the reasoning above, template argument deduction will deduce `T` into `int&` for your first argument since input is an `lvalue`.

Template argument deduction will try to match the type of the second argument but for the second argument since input is an rvalue following the rules above `T` will be deduced to `int`.

At this point the compiler throws its hands up in the air and screams "*dude `T`'s deducted type must match for all input arguments*".

Answer (score 2):

When working to non-superficial depth with forwarding references<sup>(1)</sup>, it's important to understand how they actually work and not treat them as "magic."

All the "magic" of forwarding references is this ruling in the standard:

When type deduction happens for parameter type `T &&` where `T` is a deduced type, and an lvalue of type `U` is used as the argument, the type `U &` is used for type deduction instead of `U`.

Let's take this example:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T&& a);

int i = 42;
```

What happens when you call `foo(42)`: `42` is an rvalue of type `int`. Therefore, `T` will be deduced to `int` and the type of `a` will therefore be `int &&`, an rvalue reference to `int`.

What happens when you call `foo(i)`: `i` is an lvalue of type `int`. Because of the forwarding reference rules, deduction will happen as if `int &` was the type. `T` is therefore deduced to `int &`; the type of `a` is therefore "`int & &&`", which reference-collapses to `int &`.

With this in mind, it's clear why your example fails. The same `T` would have to be deduced as both `int &` (because of `n`) and as `int` (because of `std::move(n)`). So naturally, deduction fails.

If you want each of the parameters to be a forwarding reference on its own, you need a separate template parameter for each:

```
template<class T, class U>
void f(T&& a, U&& b)
{}
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Notice that as per the proposal [N4164](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf), which has been accepted into the working paper, the preferred term is *forwarding references.*